# How to duplicate elements of a matrix without using the repmat function

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given the matrix `I = [1,2;3,4]`, I would like to duplicate the elements to create a matrix `I2` such that:

```
I2 = [1 1 1 2 2 2
      1 1 1 2 2 2
      1 1 1 2 2 2
      3 3 3 4 4 4 
      3 3 3 4 4 4
      3 3 3 4 4 4]
```

Other than using `repmat`, what other methods or functions are available?

Comment: @thewaywewalk - bless you.  The previous version had crappy formatting.

Comment: @rayryreng well no, just the curly brackets were missing :p

Comment: @thewaywewalk - Still. Bless you lol.

Comment: @zaleha I wouldn't use `I` to denote a matrix as it is usually used for the identity matrix (or for images in some applications).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
>> N = 3 %// Number of times to replicate a number in each dimension
>> I = [1,2;3,4];
>> kron(I, ones(N))

ans =

     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     3     3     4     4     4
```

---

This probably deserves some explanation in case you're not aware of what `kron` does.  `kron` stands for the [Kronecker Tensor Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  `kron` between two matrices `A` of size `m x n` and `B` of size `p x q` creates an output matrix of size `mp x nq` such that:

[image]

Therefore, for each coefficient in `A`, we take this value, multiply it with every value in the matrix `B` and we position these matrices in the same order as we see in `A`.  As such, if we let `A = I`, and `B` be the 3 x 3 matrix full of ones, you thus get the above result.

Comment: If I wouldn't have answered your comment I would have posted this :D - +1

Comment: @thewaywewalk - lol sorry.  As soon as I saw your edit, it clued in.  Thanks for your +1 though!

Comment: No problem. Please accept one of our answers when ready. This tells everyone you don't need any more help. Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng nice answer, but I wouldn't use `I` to denote a matrix as it is usually used for the identity matrix (or for images in some applications).

Comment: @Shai - You are certainly correct about that, but the OP defined it as `I` so I figured I'd stay consistent with the notation... makes it easier for him/her to copy and paste it into MATLAB.  BTW, thanks for the compliments :)

Answer (score 4):

Using indexing:

```
I = [1, 2; 3, 4];                                           %// original matrix
n = 3;                                                      %// repetition factor
I2 = I(ceil(1/n:1/n:size(I,1)), ceil(1/n:1/n:size(I,2)));   %// result
```

Answer (score 3):

One-liner with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
R = 3; %// Number of replications
I2 = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,permute(I,[3 1 4 2]),zeros(R,1,R)),R*size(I,1),[])
```

---

Sample run -

```
I =
     3     2     5
     9     8     9
I2 =
     3     3     3     2     2     2     5     5     5
     3     3     3     2     2     2     5     5     5
     3     3     3     2     2     2     5     5     5
     9     9     9     8     8     8     9     9     9
     9     9     9     8     8     8     9     9     9
     9     9     9     8     8     8     9     9     9
```

Comment: `permute` still confuses me at times.  I can never visualize how the matrices are reshaped. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng I'm getting the hang of it in 3D. But Divakar seems not have no limit as to the number of dimensions! :-)

Comment: @rayryeng To fully appreciate `bsxfun`, `permute` is just very crucial! Just play around more with it! :)

Comment: @Divakar - Oh I try to whenever I have the chance!  I just have to play around with it some more to wrap my head around it.